# How to use Java package in eclipse

Tags: java, postgresql

I am beginner of Java.

I want to use Java package here https://github.com/htorun/dbtableprinter

But I am not sure where I should put the download file.
Using command prompt or eclipse, I want to use the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to just be a Java file. So instead of adding it like you would a package, you would just add the DBTablePrinter.java file into your program. Then you should be able to use the static helper methods.

I would probably put this in a "helper" folder. Then you should be able to either import it, or just do "helper/DbTablePrinter.printTable();"

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. To add the *.java* file to your project, I would do it in a *helper* folder/package where you can use it with import (package) or *[helper-folder-name]/java-file-name*. Like @Phil suggested in the previous answer.
2. put your class in a project and use it as a dependency in your project.